# SWT selection event after deleting selection

Tags: java, swt

I'm making a simple menu to delete items on a tree. However, after deleting the items, the tree does not receive a selection event, therefore, the code in the listener does not execute (the listener, in the full code, updates a part of the UI).

I have simplified the code below, leaving out details. It is something like this:

```
tree.addListener (SWT.Selection, new Listener(){
     public void handleEvent(Event e) {
     (....)
    }
}
```

I also tried this:

```
    tree.addSelectionListener (new SelectionListener(){
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e){
            (...)
        }
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            (...)
        }
    }
```

On my menu action (delete selection), there is this:

```
    TreeItem [] selected = tree.getSelection();
    tree.deselectAll();
    if (selected.length > 0)
    {
      for( TreeItem i : selected){
          i.dispose();
      }
    }
```

After deleting the selection, my selection listener does not fire. It does fire if I deselect all itens using the ctrl+click combination.

What should I do? Is there a way to fire the SWT.Selection event to the tree after deleting the itens or should I isolate the code inside the listener to call it again? Shouldn't the tree.deselectAll() fire a Selection event?

Comment: The `if (selected.length > 0)` part cannot possibly compile, because you do not appear to have declared `selected` anywhere. Are you hiding things from us?

Comment: Yes, I tried to simplify the code to avoid confusing stuff in between. Sorry about that, it did get confusing, I'll edit. Shouldn't I try to simplify the code to ask questions?

Comment: I notice now that I did declare it, TreeItem [] selected = tree.getSelection();

Comment: Yes, you should try to simplify, but it is a fine and difficult art: you should not remove parts that are (or may be) pertinent to finding a solution.

Comment: Wh00ps! C-:= I do not know what I thought I was reading.

Comment: I guess the indentation threw me off.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the identation

Comment: I do not see a problem.  Also, I do not understand what you mean by `therefore, the UI does not update properly.`  What did you expect to see, and what do you see instead?

Comment: @MikeNakis, I expected the code in the listener to be executed. I'll change the phrasing on the question, thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send a selection event programmatically with:

```
Event event = new Event();
event.widget = tree;
event.display = tree.getDisplay();
event.type = SWT.Selection;
tree.notifyListeners(SWT.Selection, event);
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixes my problem!
Shouldn't the event be fired automatically by the tree.deselectAll(), though?

Comment: The `Tree.deselectAll` disables sending a notification. So I suppose this is part of the SWT design.

Comment: Well, SWT is lame.  I looked at the documentation for tree.deselectAll() and it does not say anything about selection notifications being suppressed by that method.  It should.

Answer (score 1):

Have same situation and found 
[this](https://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t30271.html) link mentioning, that programmatically setSelection may never send this event due to design, so always send it (if needed) programmatically after setting too